# start: caddy process exited with error: exit status 1

Tags: webserver

I am trying to run Caddy (v2.1.1) web server on a Ubuntu 18.04.

After installing caddy (`apt install caddy`) and running it by caddy start I keep getting the error below:

```
root@vds:~# caddy start
run: loading initial config: loading new config: starting caddy administration endpoint: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:2019: bind: address already in use
start: caddy process exited with error: exit status 1
```

I suspect it is related to the initialisation through `CaddyFile`.

Any idea and solution regarding how to solve the issue and run the app is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This error means that caddy service is already running. *After installation from `apt` it's started automatically.*

You should stop it

```
caddy stop
```

and try again :)

Comment: Vwala!!... this little post saved me countless days and red yes with tears :)